# OSX Mavericks Kernel Panic

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I am running Mavericks on a mid 2013 macbook air (haswell). I have been getting multiple kernel panics a day for about the past week. It isn't happening on any specific task or time - I can't isolate it to anything. Sometimes i'm coding in Vim, writing an email, or playing League of Legends. I finally got so frustrated last night, I completely wiped the computer (formatting the drive in disc utility then reinstalling Mavericks). Here is the panic log.

I would really appreciate any help you can offer with this, it's really frustrating.

> Anonymous UUID:       9AE0CA41-ADD9-CA6F-9872-CCB660376C1F
>
> Tue Jul  8 14:38:02 2014 panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800a6521dd):
>   "zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone kalloc.8192,
>   likely due to memory leak in zone kalloc.64 (2470632192 total bytes,
>   38603601 elements
>   allocated)"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.110.17/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2494
>   Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff8126b23c70 :
>   0xffffff800a622f79  0xffffff8126b23cf0 : 0xffffff800a6521dd 
>   0xffffff8126b23df0 : 0xffffff800a62aa3f  0xffffff8126b23e20 :
>   0xffffff800a613026  0xffffff8126b23e50 : 0xffffff800a626b51 
>   0xffffff8126b23e80 : 0xffffff800a6139c5  0xffffff8126b23ef0 :
>   0xffffff800a61e013  0xffffff8126b23f70 : 0xffffff800a6c9b8d 
>   0xffffff8126b23fb0 : 0xffffff800a6f3f66
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
>
> Mac OS version: 13E28
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT
>   2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   BBFADD17-672B-35A2-9B7F-E4B12213E4B8 Kernel slide:
>   0x000000000a400000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff800a600000 System model
>   name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977E5)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 62565348323087 vm objects:17939040 vm
>   object hash entri:2533080 VM map entries:3054880 pv_list:12570624 vm
>   pages:146947752 kalloc.16:205691024 kalloc.32:276913728
>   kalloc.64:2470632192 kalloc.128:9646080 kalloc.256:9203712
>   kalloc.512:8560640 kalloc.1024:4419584 kalloc.2048:1556480
>   kalloc.4096:8900608 kalloc.8192:8511488 ipc ports:3356640 ipc
>   kmsgs:33210368 threads:1839264 uthreads:1187280 vnodes:20281680
>   namecache:4455360 HFS node:27107888 HFS fork:8265728
>   cluster_write:1448568 decmpfs_cnode:2390976 buf.8192:7487488 ubc_info
>   zone:5565120 vnode pager structur:2529040 Kernel Stacks:13500416
>   PageTables:60256256 Kalloc.Large:23017809
>
> Backtrace suspected of leaking: (outstanding bytes: 56448)
>   0xffffff800a651ce3 0xffffff800a62aa3f 0xffffff800aa4ef9c
>   0xffffff800aa4f0d0 0xffffff800aa4f086 0xffffff800aa64be6
>   0xffffff800aa963be 0xffffff800aa4d85e 0xffffff800aa4da27
>   0xffffff800aa91233 0xffffff800aa96a34 0xffffff7f8aed7eb8
>   0xffffff7f8aed304c
>         Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>            com.razer.common.razerhid(9.35)[0A917EFD-D323-36E1-AE4A-288047813989]@0xffffff7f8aecd000->0xffffff7f8aee5fff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(683.4.0)[7595281D-D047-3715-9044-98F46B62F845]@0xffffff7f8acab000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily(2.0.0)[994495B5-FB34-3DB5-B47A-D2A732E52F33]@0xffffff7f8ad6d000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver(660.4.0)[ABEFEB9E-8AF5-3927-93D6-205DD1EA6425]@0xffffff7f8adf2000
>               dependency: com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver(4.2.6f1)[37DE58F3-99F5-319C-B922-79CB88FC5C67]@0xffffff7f8aeb9000
>
> last loaded kext at 61937907837580:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7f8c861000,
>   size 49152) last unloaded kext at 62069214475178:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7f8c861000,
>   size 32768) loaded kexts: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.12
>   org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt    4.3.12
>   org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB   4.3.12 org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv  4.3.12
>   com.razer.common.razerhid 9.35 com.apple.filesystems.smbfs    2.0.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 80.14
>   com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.13
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.6.3f4 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.2.6f1
>   com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.28
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.0.9d6
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim  1.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.ntfs    3.11
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays 360.8.14
>   com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess    1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   1.1.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 4.26.0
>   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.6f1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.4d1 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight   170.3.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 8.2.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul    8.2.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   3.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver   10.21
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.BootCache   35 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter  404
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.6.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    3.0.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub  683.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 660.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI  5.0.2
>   com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  3.8.1b2
>   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 842.21.65
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 683.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
>   com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 153 com.apple.security.quarantine   3
>   com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
>   com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.6f1
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP  2.2.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio    2.9.5f8
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.7fc2
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.14 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC  3.1.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.6.3f4
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.6.3f4
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.7.1d6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.12d1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 91.1 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport  2.4.1
>   com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl  3.6.22
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2  98.22
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 4.2.6f1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.2.6f1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    660.4.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.6.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.6.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.6.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  3.1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 3.1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  3.1.7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 1.4.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   1.4.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 650.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    656.4.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 170.15
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver  24
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver    245.13
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.6.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   660.4.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily  4.5.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.3b4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  2.0.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   3.3.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 640.36
>   com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b5
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport    24
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController  2.0.34
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac   2.0.34
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi   2.0.34
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   683.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
>   com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
>   com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    2 com.apple.driver.DiskImages   371.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.9 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread   1
>   com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please use code formatting for Terminal output! Quote formatting doesn't preserve line breaks and is very difficult to read.

Comment: General advice on troubleshooting kernel panics is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 5):

According to your log you have a Razer mouse!

`Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.razer.common.razerhid(9.35)[0A917EFD-D323-36E1-AE4A-288047813989]@0xffffff7f8aecd000->0xffffff7f8aee5fff`

It looks like your Razer mouse and/or its driver caused that panic.

That causes the `BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer` (the app that switches your windows) to fail.

Disconnect the mouse and test.

Comment: So far it seems to have fixed the issue it's been a few hours without any issues. Going to use it for another day or two and see what happens. Thanks @buscar

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If satisfied please check the answer as completed.

Comment: I can confirm you that I'm experiencing the same issue with my new Razer mouse, 4 kernel panics in less than 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

I also have a razer mouse. My computer did not (yet) have multiple kernel panics a day. I guess it's the driver. I didn't install the razer mouse driver.

Comment: I contacted Razr and they replaced the mouse.